# How I can separate version of libraries in "build.gradle" app

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to separate versions of the libraries to have all of them in one location in order to save time and complexity.

I saw a guy in some comment in some blog that sais the way he use to do this. He posted the next screens.

[image: First Screen]

[image: Second Screen]

I can't use this way to construct the gradle, but I think that is a good way.

My Project build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

// Definition of versions of libraries
ext {

    toolVersions = [

            android :[
                    versionCode    : 1,
                    versionName    : "0.0.1",
                    minSdk          : 16,
                    targetSdk       : 26,
                    compileSdk      : 26,
                    buildTools      : "26.0.2",
                    support         : "26.1.0"
            ],
            espressoCore   : "2.2.2",
            junit           : "4.12"

    ]

    libVersions = [
            glide   :   "4.2.0",
            flubber :   "1.0.1"
    ]

}
```

My app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion toolVersions.android.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion toolVersions.android.buildTools
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maol.brastlewark"
        minSdkVersion toolVersions.android.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion toolVersions.android.targetSdk
        versionCode toolVersions.android.versionCode
        versionName toolVersions.android.versionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:' + toolVersion.espressoCore, {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // SUPPORT LIBRARIES
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:' toolVersion.support
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$rootProject.toolVersion.support"
    testCompile "junit:junit:$rootProject.toolVersion.junit"

    // IMAGE LOADER LIBRARY
    compile "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$rootProject.libVersions.glide"
    annotationProcessor "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$rootProject.libVersions.glide"

    // VIEW ANIMATIONS
    compile "com.appolica:flubber:$rootProject.libVersions.flubber"

}
```

I don't know how to used this in the build.gradle (app). Anyone in the room can advised me something?

Thank you

Answer (score 15):

You can create a file (for example `gradleScript/dependencies.gradle`):

```
ext {
    //Version
    supportLibrary = '26.1.0'

    //Support Libraries dependencies
    supportDependencies = [
            design           :         "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}",
            recyclerView     :         "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            cardView         :         "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            appCompat        :         "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}",
            supportAnnotation:         "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibrary}",
    ]
}
```

In the top level file `build.gradle` add:

```
// Load dependencies
apply from: 'gradleScript/dependencies.gradle'
```

In the `module1/build.gradle`:

```
// Module build file

dependencies {
    //......
    compile supportDependencies.appCompat
    compile supportDependencies.design
}
```

Comment: How to implement directly whole `supportDependencies` group?

Comment: I might be late but this might help beginners : to apply whole `supportDependencies` group do `supportDependencies.values()`.

Comment: This approach doesn't show warning like https://miro.medium.com/max/3708/1*hgOycRk5Rds-gOS80Hz6IA.png

Comment: this doesnt tell whether the update is available or not

Answer (score 4):

## Solution that preserves lint update checks

You can use the same construct as in your question. To preserve the lint update checks you'd only include the version number (rather than the entire dependency name).

### Create an `ext` block in your project level `build.gradle` file

Each item in the ext block acts like a map so we can organize dependency versions in an array.

```
ext {
    playServicesVersions = [
            base    : '17.6.0',
            location: '18.0.0',
            maps    : '17.0.0'
    ]

    supportVersions = [
            nameHere: '3.0.0'
    ]
}
```

### Access dependency versions

Note that curly braces are used here because more than one variable is accessed.

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${playServicesVersions.base}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesVersions.location}"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersions.maps}"
}
```

---

### Lint checks still active

[image: Lint check still active]

Answer (score 1):

To make that possible you can declare `ext{}` block in your build.gradle file.

```
ext {
    def AAVersion = '4.0-SNAPSHOT' // change this to your desired version
}

dependencies {
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
```

If you want to work with arrays:

```
ext {
    supportDependencies = [
        design : "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}",
        // whatever lib...
    ]
}
```

then when you want to call it:

```
dependencies {
    compile supportDependencies.design
}
```

Comment: The ext definition in my project build.gradle I think that it is fine. The problem is that I don't know how to call this variables in the app build.gradle

Comment: just follow my answer, use " not ' and put $ before calling the version. that way: "groupId:artifactId:$versionDef"

Comment: when I've tried to put def as prefix of the array, the IDE lint give me an error. Could you write me an example of the array toolVersion->android for example? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the dependencies in your **settings.gradle**:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            alias('protobuf').to('com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.15.8')
            alias('snappy').to('org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:1.1.8.4')
            alias('junit').to('junit:junit:4.13.2')
        }
    }
}
```

And then use them in **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
    api libs.protobuf
    api libs.snappy

    testImplementation libs.junit
}
```

It works for multi-project builds as well.

Please refer to [official docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) for details.