# Is it possible to get dependency version at runtime, including from library itself?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

### Background

Suppose I make an Android library called "MySdk", and I publish it on Jitpack/Maven.

The user of the SDK would use it by adding just the dependency of :

```
implementation 'com.github.my-sdk:MySdk:1.0.1'
```

What I'd like to get is the "1.0.1" part from it, whether I do it from within the Android library itself (can be useful to send to the SDK-server which version is used), or from the app that uses it (can be useful to report about specific issues, including via Crashlytics).

### The problem

I can't find any reflection or gradle task to reach it.

### What I've tried

Searching about it, if I indeed work on the Android library (that is used as a dependency), all I've found is that I can manage the version myself, via code.

Some said I could use BuildConfig of the package name of the library, but then it means that if I forget to update the code a moment before I publish the dependency, it will use the wrong value. Example of using this method:

```
plugins {
...
}
final def sdkVersion = "1.0.22"

android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            buildConfigField "String", "SDK_VERSION", "\"" + sdkVersion + "\""
        }
       debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "SDK_VERSION", "\"" + sdkVersion + "-unreleased\""
        }
    }
```

Usage is just checking the value of `BuildConfig.SDK_VERSION` (after building).

Another possible solution is perhaps from gradle task inside the Android-library, that would be forced to be launched whenever you build the app that uses this library. However, I've failed to find how do it (found something [**here**](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-task-or-method-to-find-resolved-version-of-the-dynamic-dependency/32054/2?u=androiddeveloperlb))

### The question

Is it possible to query the dependency version from within the Android library of the dependency (and from the app that uses it, of course), so that I could use it during runtime?

Something automatic, that won't require me to update it before publishing ?

Maybe using Gradle task that is defined in the library, and forced to be used when building the app that uses the library?

Comment: _"if I forget to update the code a moment before I publish the dependency, it will use the wrong value"_. So where are you setting the version number now? It seems to me like you need to set it _somewhere_ regardless, and that it should be a part of your release procedure to always update the version number.

Comment: Technically you don't have to do it, as each commit is generating some ID on Jitpack. But, to create a nice number, you just create a new release on Github and then Jitpack gets it. If just once I would forget to update the code before release, it could be an issue. I want to avoid the need to change the code for this

Comment: Alright. Well, the most obvious way I can think of would still be to set a `versionName` in your library's `build.gradle` (e.g. inside `android {  defaultConfig { }}`, and then use that as the single source of truth for what the library's version is. And then it's your responsibility to update this property for each release. Put it on  a checklist of things that need to be done before publishing a new version.

Comment: You can't use it in a single place. Github doesn't look at code. Github doesn't know when you wish to create a new release automatically by code. What you wrote is what I know that's possible. Again, the problem here is that it's manual and can lead to mistakes.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. So, you want to retrieve the version number from the Gradle dependency when the version number may not appear in your code (Gradle files, source, etc.) at all? In your example, you want to get to "1.0.1" when your code may indicate version "1.0.0" because you forgot to update it. Is that right?

Comment: @Cheticamp Kinda. When someone uses the dependency, I want to fetch the version that he has used there. Is it possible? Maybe possible via Gradle each time it gets built?

Comment: I came across this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70592865/6287910) that is similar to your question. (No answers, though.) The question references [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-info-play) that seems to indicate that the dependency information is not otherwise available except as outline in that documentation. Unfortunately, the dependencies are encrypted with a Google Play signing key and won't be available to developers.

Comment: @Cheticamp I find it weird. While building, can't I run a script that gets the versions of the dependencies, and then store them in something that can be used during runtime of the app? Why would it matter if it's a signed app or not?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Gradle task to capture the version of the library as presented in the build.gradle dependencies and store the version information in *BuildConfig.java* for each build type.

The task below captures the version of the "appcompat" dependency as an example.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
}

task CaptureLibraryVersion {
    def libDef = project.configurations.getByName('implementation').allDependencies.matching {
        it.group.equals("androidx.appcompat") && it.name.equals("appcompat")
    }
    if (libDef.size() > 0) {
        android.buildTypes.each {
            it.buildConfigField 'String', 'LIB_VERSION', "\"${libDef[0].version}\""
        }
    }
}
```

For my example, the "appcompat" version was 1.4.0. After the task is run, *BuildConfig.java* contains

```
// Field from build type: debug
public static final String LIB_VERSION = "1.4.0";
```

You can reference this field in code with `BuildConfig.LIB_VERSION`. The task can be automatically run during each build cycle.

Comment: That's good. How do you make it automatic upon normal building, though, so that whoever uses the library would trigger it, and so that the library (and whoever is using it) could reach this field? After all, I can't tell whoever uses the library "First run this gradle task before using this library". Also, how could I reach this field from within the library, as it obviously doesn't have a dependency usage of itself? Probably via reflection, right?

Comment: I was thinking that automatically running the task would be easy, but now I don't think that is true with the dependency. I believe that the user of your library would have to make some change to their code. Since the versioning might be inconsistent, I will suggest that you capture the version number and the publication date/time. You could then report the version and the publication date to identify the actual version that is being used. Those two values, together, will be unique and can be captured during you library's build. (You could also just use the publication date.)

Comment: I don't understand. You are suggesting a different solution?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible without having the user make changes to specifically address the versioning. I am simply suggesting capturing the build time of the library which can be captured and stored within the library. The build time will uniquely identify the version and will be readily accessible. It's just a thought.

Comment: Oh you mean that upon build, it will store the date&time (epoch or something similar) as a version, right? It won't be based on what's shown to the user of the library, though, so it's harder to map between the two...

Comment: True, and it might be confusing. I would look at automating the release process that will take the versioning completely out of your hands. If that is not acceptable, you could just automatically check to make sure that the version has changed in the release build since the last build. Of course, as you say, the version in the dependency is divorced from that in the library project, so a mistake can be made there as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to your question is 'yes' - you can do it. But if you want a simple solution to do it so the answer transforms to 'no' - there is no simple solution.

The libraries are in the classpath of your package, thus the only way to access their info at the runtime would be to record needed information during the compilation time and expose it to your application at the runtime.

There are two major 'correct' ways and you kinda have described them in your question but I will elaborate a bit.

1. The most correct way and relatively easy way is to expose all those variables as BuildConfig or String res values via gradle pretty much as described [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#simplify-app-development). You can try to generify the approach for this using local-prefs(or helper gradle file) to store versions and use them everywhere it is needed. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies), [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46932400/9248201)
2. The second correct, but much more complicated way is to write a gradle plugin or at least some set of tasks for collecting needed values during compile-time and providing an interface(usually via your app assets or res) for your app to access them during runtime. A pretty similar thing is already implemented for google libraries in [`Google Play services Plugins`](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins) so it would be a good place to start.

All the other possible implementations are variations of the described two or their combination.

Comment: I don't want to talk about manual solutions. I'm interested in something that I can query (in both the library and the app that uses it) and without the need to modify anywhere in the Android library. I've checked the link of the second solution, but I don't see it in the gradle files. Are you sure it's there?

Comment: @androiddeveloper as far as I know there is no open automatic solution for this issue. Regarding the link - something similar to what you want is implemented in strict-version-matcher-plugin but you will have to change it and I assume it won't be that fast to make those changes. sorry, mate

Comment: But you wrote that Gradle could help there. I don't see any querying of version on gradle file on the repository you've mentioned. It seems like just a constant there, of `project.ext.version = '1.2.3'` . This is very similar to any solution of having a constant on the library, which means you need to manually change it

Comment: Well yeah - collecting should be done manually. I assume some libraries do expose their version in some way but we cannot count on that. The semi-automatic solution could be implemented using ext{} with a map of libraries and appropriate versions. And to collect them you will have to write some task or a plain loop with res/config exposing - the approach will still require a lot of boilerplate. Once more - I don't know any automatic solution - only manual/semi-automatic ones

Comment: That's the thing. I don't want to put the version anywhere in the library. I want it to be possible to queried automatically, probably triggered by the project that uses the dependency.

Comment: I don't know about the ready solution for that, sorry.

Comment: ok thank you. I hope it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create buildSrc folder and manage dependencies in [there](https://proandroiddev.com/better-dependencies-management-using-buildsrc-kotlin-dsl-eda31cdb81bf).
after that, you can import & use Versions class in anywhere of your app.

Comment: Have you tried it on the library side?