# Is there a way to get the dependencies information for static analysis of the android apk file?

Tags: android, apk, static-analysis

I was doing apk static analysis and want to fetch all the dependencies used by the developer for the app. Is there a way to fetch the list of dependency library name and version from the APK file?

I was going through android documentation and found that while compile time .properties file get generated and which hold the dependency related information which Google play service use while submitting an app.

reference: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency-info-play

**Dependency information for Play Console When building your app using**

> AGP 4.0.0 and higher, the plugin includes metadata that describes the
> library dependencies that are compiled into your app. When uploading
> your app, the Play Console inspects this metadata to provide alerts
> for known issues with SDKs and dependencies your app uses, and, in
> some cases, provide actionable feedback to resolve those issues.
>
> The data is compressed, encrypted by a Google Play signing key, and
> stored in the signing block of your release app. We recommend keeping
> this dependencies file for a safe and positive user experience.
> However, if you’d rather not share this information, you can opt out
> by including the following dependenciesInfo block in your module’s
> build.gradle file:

Comment: https://medium.com/camerakit/finding-permissions-and-dependencies-in-an-apk-c91e629ce706

this link might help you

Comment: For Andorid library detection check one of these: LibScout, LibRadar, LibPecker - source : https://lilicoding.github.io/papers/zhan2020automated.pdf